# Admin logging in as a User without knowing user password?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to provide an admin functionality where an admin is able to login as another user without knowing their password. All the site content is permission controlled. My questions are -

- Should I logout the admin user before switching to the user account?
  Does that mean admin have to re-login?
- If I need to switch back to admin account - how do I go about this as the "User" don't have admin permissions but I previously logged in as an admin?
- Any other thing I need to keep in mind?

What do you suggest?

Comment: How would you know if the user was an admin if you logged him out? Also, why would you want to do this? I wouldnt want some admin having access to my account

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter but suggestions don't have to be CI specific!

Comment: Bono - this is a requirement as sometimes users have certain problems in their accounts and an admin can go in to fix that for them.

Comment: At Facebook you can "look at your profile as other users view it", I think it's a nice feature and if it fits your site you COULD do it. However this is not a common feature. You have to redo you auth-script and login-script so admins have a change to pass as another user.

Comment: @Bono: There are lots of perfectly valid reasons for user impersonation. Checking if complex permissions are correct is one of them. Besides that, the admin might have direct database access anyway so it just makes things easier for him.

Comment: Hmm yeah seems logical, just the first thing that came to mind with someone else having access to my account makes me go.. nope :P

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with CI, but here's a generic solution:

When choosing to impersonate a user, you:

- Store the *user id* in the session as *admin user id*.
- Replace the *user id* in the session with the target user id (i.e. do whatever would happen during a successful login)

If an *admin user id* is present in the session, display an "end impersonation" link somewhere. When clicking that link, you:

- Replace the *user id* in the session with the *admin user id*.
- Remove the *admin user id* from the session.

Comment: Hmm .. I usually clear the sessions to logout a user - so just thinking I may have to manually unset() "user" or "admin" related session data when switching back and forth? (in order to keep admin id in session)

Answer (score 2):

1. Dont destroy the admin session
2. check if admin session is set

   ```
   if(isset($_SESSION['admin']))
   {
         //authenticate the user without checking the password,only check the uname 
   }
   else
   {
       //authenticate the user by checking both username and password
   }
   ```
3. Remember to keep two separate session for a user and admin.

I hope that will do

Comment: its all permission based so there are no clear-cut roles for "admin" and "other users"